# The scale of my maps are HUGE! What can I do about it?

Tags: tools, roll20

Newbie GM here again, now confused about map sizes: I'm overlaying the maps from [this site](http://theredepic.bigcartel.com/products) onto R20 for a Hoard of the Dragon Queen adventure. The 'problem' (if there is one, there might not be) is that, if I enlarge the map such that the scale (100-300 feet) spans the right amount of squares in the grid (60, if math-fu didn't fail me), the thing is HUGE.

Tokens are barely visible (I added two to test the size, and after moving around a bit, I just couldn't find them. I have a small screen though =[ ). Am I doing this right? If I am, what tips do you have to make tokens more visible, and the map/battlefield easier to manage?

Comment: I and others are pretty meh on the fact that they went with a 10 feet grid in many of the maps. Really makes things more complicated and causes the scaling issues you mentioned.

Comment: It ended up working out pretty well for me when I ran Pathfinder on roll20 with a map that ended up being huge.  Players started zoomed out so they could find the active area (because I had most of the map hidden) then zoomed in on the tokens once they found them.  It took them an extra minute or two to start because they had to find the right spot and zoom in, but it wasn't a big deal.

Comment: You can always Shift + Click (Hold) to force everyone's camera on a point of your choosing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maps, especially the ones for Skyreach castle *are* quite huge. The best two things you can *and should* do is cut them into separate maps. There are three maps in each image, use any image editor (even paint would work here), to cut them apart and upload them separately.

Second, use the zoom in and out functions here, this is not too huge for R20 to handle. Make sure you use the "fit to grid" tool to highlight a 3x3 section and get the grid sized properly. Make sure your canvas is sized for the number of squares you are using.

If you're still having problems, figure out where the action is and only use *part* of each map.

These are big maps and you're quite unlikely to need the *whole* thing for an encounter. Break down where your PCs are likely to be and crop the maps so that only those locations are uploaded and used. Obviously this may leave you in a bit of a lurch when it comes to your PCs improvising and going off the map, but in this case, either add more to the grid or wing it with a new one.

For the Greenest map, *don't* use that map for your combats. Identify the locations of interest and find smaller maps. This does mean that this map is less useful, but you can hand draw your locations, or find other art references. That particular map is *not* a good combat map as it doesn't have the level of detail you'd want for combat.